# Обезумевший RayCast

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Делаю проект учебный - игру на unity. Вроде бы работала стрельба простая на RayCast'ах. Но тут в очередной проверке другого функционала, было замечено что абсолютно рандомный выстрел может произойти абсолютно из неизвестной мне точки. То есть на дуле автомата установлен объект(shootPoint), координаты которого не меняются никак. Но лучи создаются периодически из другой абсолютно точки. Причем не единожды, а каждый следующий "косой" луч будет создан тоже из неизвестной точки. Похоже на какой то пранк, вроде бы все просто - но я не понимаю что не так.

[image: Лучи]

```
RaycastHit hit;

    if(Physics.Raycast(shootPoint.position, shootPoint.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(shootPoint.position, shootPoint.transform.forward, Color.red, 100);
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name + " GOTCHA!");

        GameObject hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
        ReactiveTarget target = hitObject.GetComponent<ReactiveTarget>();

        GameObject shootParticlesEffect = Instantiate(shootParticles, hit.point, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hit.normal));
        GameObject bulletHole = Instantiate(bulletImpact, hit.point, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, hit.normal));
        bulletHole.transform.SetParent(hit.transform);

        Destroy(shootParticlesEffect, 1.5f);
        Destroy(bulletHole, 3f);

        if (target != null)
        {
            target.ReactToHit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: рендерить луч 100 секунд? Вероятно это не "рандомный выстрел", а просто не очищенный луч. То есть выстрел был из точки Х, а потом оружие переместилось и визуально кажется что случайно.

Comment: @ValeraKvip я стоял на месте и стрелял в одну точку, при этом лучи созданы из разных мест. Сто секунд это время отображения луча для дебага, что бы я успел заскринить и т.д

Comment: Попробуй вывести shootPoint.position в лог во время выстрела. Будут разные или нет? Может есть анимация типа отдачи или что-то такое? По картинке не понять в чем проблема.

Comment: @ValeraKvip логи разные да. Смещение по всем координатам. Только у меня нет в целом никаких скриптов или подобного что бы меняло позицию автомата/рук. Да и я могу N раз выстрелить в одну точку, но на N+1 он сместиться.

Comment: Можете показать мне например первые 5 или 10 логи. Может там симметрия есть какой нибудь? И если можно покажите ещё лог этого - shootPoint.transform.forward.

Comment: @AltF4 в общем каким то чудесным образом я все починил. Но из всего этого я вынес только то, что проблема была в самих объектах. То есть ни код, ни какая либо анимация не виноваты.